# How to pass database query to strings using dplyr filter function

Tags: r, database, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

I'm trying to pass database query to strings using dplyr filter functions

here is the code

```
main<-tbl(portal, "account")%>%
  filter( dates >= "1640991600" & dates <= "1641077999")%>%
  collect()%>%
  as.character()
```

but it's not working, any help would be welcome

Comment: Hi user16087142, you need to provide us at least a bit of data or the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect()` will return an object of class `data.frame` which is a table that can not be converted into a character vector implicitly. Instead of `as.character()`, you can do `write_csv("query_result.csv")` to save the received table into a file or `pull(col1) %>% as.character()` to get a character vector of the column named `col1`.

Comment: Thank you danlooo
What I did was to save it as you have suggested in your answer("query_result.csv"), then
read it back using read.csv and set the colClasses to "character"